# Brining row where column valus is null

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a store procedure which brings the data as shown below . I'm new to SSRS reporting, I would like to show only those row where "email" column is null. How can i achieve it in SSRS ? As i mentioned I'm very new to this , any screenshot will help me a lot. Thank you for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, you'll want to change the row visibility to hide rows with a value in that column.  I assume you're using a table or matrix to layout this data.  You'll want to right click on the row where your data fields are entered. Specifically, the grey box at the left of the row.

[image]

From there, you'll need to select the option to `Show or hide based on an expression`.

[image]

And finally, you'll need to enter an expression that finds the values in the email field. I'm not exactly sure what the field names are called but something like the following expression should do it.

```
= Not IsNothing(Fields!EmailField.Value)
```

This will check the field where you get the email value with a built-in function of `IsNothing`.  Additionally, since you want fields that do not contain values, the `Not` keyword reverses the results.  If the function evaluates to true and a value is present, the row will be hidden and vice versa.

Comment: You are a Star my friend. it work like a charm. Thank you so much for your time to help me out. I truly appreciate your help and your valuable time.